# Indra turning to female due to the curse of Trnabindu

Tags: scripture, indra

Story of Indra turning into female, due to the curse, has been mentioned in the *`CHAPTER 63: Indra's rescue from the female sex`* of Narasimha purana.

Indra once abducted the Citrasena, the wife of Kubera with the help of Kamadeva. Later Nadijangha, the sister of Vibhishana tries to help Kubera. Indra identify her and kill her. Due to the act of killing, he got a curse from Trnabindu. Due to the curse, the Indra turns into female.

Are there any mentions in any other scriptures regarding this curse to Indra?